# How do you resolve conflicting linting rules in VSCode between eslint and typescript-eslint

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

I have my eslinting rules as follows

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
    mocha: true
  },
  extends: [
    "standard-with-typescript"
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  globals: {
    Atomics: 'readonly',
    SharedArrayBuffer: 'readonly'
  },
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    project: "./tsconfig.json"
  },
  rules: {
    "quotes": ["warn", "single"],
    "indent": ["warn", "tab", { "ignoreComments": true }],
    "no-tabs": 0,
    "padded-blocks": 0,
    "semi": 0,
    "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
    "spaced-comment": 0,
    "no-multiple-empty-lines": 0,
    "space-before-function-paren": 0,
    "camelcase": 0,
    "prefer-const": "warn",
    "space-infix-ops": "warn",
    "@typescript-eslint/strict-boolean-expressions": ["warn", {"allowNullable": true}]
  },
  plugins: [
    '@typescript-eslint',
  ],
}
```

When I open a new file that is not properly formatted to tabs, I get:

[image: expected error]

Fair enough, so I change indentation to tabs using VScode and now I get:

[image]

???

I have my settings configured so that all the extensions read from just one eslintrc file in the project root...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you didn't posted your hole `.eslintrc.js` config i can only assume that you have extends to a few off the recommended rule sets which leads to your unwanted behavior that multiple rules are running...

Depending on which one of these two rules you want you can just simply deactivate the other one by adding this to you rules eg.:

`"@typescript-eslint/indent": "off"`

This will deactivate the `@typescript-eslint/indent` rule for your project.

Comment: Ah ok thank you I will try that. added my `.eslintrc.js` file

Comment: Had a short look at `"standard-with-typescript"` which you extend, seems that this turns on `"@typescript-eslint/indent"`. If it works to deactivate one of them please mark the answer as accepted ;)

Comment: That did work. I ended up going back to standard-with-typescript and just uninstalling the typescript-eslint extension

Answer (score 0):

My preferred solution was to disable the base `indent` rule and configure an overriding `@typescript-eslint/indent` rule as suggested here: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/87b7dbbc8d25d059e34888ec28026bfb4ade2215/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/indent.md

```
"rules": {
    "indent": "off",
    "@typescript-eslint/indent": ["error", 2]
}
```

I found disabling the `@typescript-eslint/indent` rule in favour of the base `indent` rule simply hid the errors in the code editor, while still causing compilation to fail!